# AJAX not passing variable to PHP for MySQL query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to get the below AJAX script to pass a dropdown ID to PHP to run a query on, however it doesnt appear that the variable is actually being passed. When I hardcode the PHP file the query runs correctly, but when I try to do it dynamically the query returns "undefined" or nothing at all.

AJAX code

```
function ajax_post(){
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var id = document.getElementById("editorginfo").value;
      alert (id);
request.open("POST", "parse.php", true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        var return_data = request.responseText;
        alert (return_data);
        document.getElementById("orgeditname").value = return_data;
        document.getElementById("orgeditphone").value = return_data;    
    }
}

request.send("id="+id);
}
```

PHP Parse Code

```
<?php
include_once('../php_includes/db_connect.php');

$searchid = $_POST['id'];

//$searchid = 1;

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM orginfo WHERE id = $searchid';

$user_query = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($db_connect));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

$orgid = $row["id"];

 $orgname = $row["orgname"];

 $orgphone = $row["orgphone"];

 echo $orgname, $orgphone;

}
?>
```

Not really sure where the information is getting lost. When I alert the id out it is capturing the right information, so I assume the issue is in my send portion, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request header is wrong. Change this line -

```
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```